Help identify a Netflix movie about a lady locked in an attic.
So years ago there was this film on Netflix about a young woman who was meant to be on vacation but was interviewing a family about their house. 
I remember her boyfriend ringing a few times and even coming to the house to see her. 
Anyway, the family have a child an autistic son who  if I can remember has a collection of porn mags. He fancies the young lady.
Later in the film he ends up locking the lady in the attic and the parents find out about it and they go along with it.
At the end of the film the police come and we see the mentally disturbed guy jump through the attic and dies. The girl ends up getting away. 
This has been annoying me for years trying to find out what it was called as it may have been deleted from netflix.
The movie was from 2006 onwards. (May have even been 2007 or 2009) In colour. In English. Can't think of any of the actors or characters names.

From what I remember, it could be The Skeleton Key (2005). Look it up on the Wiki. It has many of the elements you have cited (the young girl interviewing in the house, the not autistic child, but a crippled man, the attic, the man jumping out of the window, etc).

Is there any way you could possibly upload a passage to the plot to back up what you think it may be?

Hello!  Could you provide more information on why this answers the question?  Thank you :)
